# Conexão com 3g instavel bloqueada no C#

Tags: c#, mysql, ftp

Pessoal tenho um sistema, que utiliza uma tabela no mysql pra verificar se existe atualização para o mesmo,
Acontece que em certos momentos, está sendo necessario que o modem seja reconectado para que o sistema possa fazer essas operações web, alguem sabe o motivo?

Comment: Você consegue acessar a internet normalmente antes de reconectar o modem (assumindo que ele já esteja conectado)?

Comment: Sim, o acesso é feito normalmente, a reconexão só é necessária para que o sistema em C# funcione, fora do sistema as paginas web são acessadas normalmente.

Comment: Ainda não obtive a resposta, infelizmente não posso ficar pedindo para os "clientes" ficarem desconectando, será que teria uma forma, de fazer essa reconexão através do C#?

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o seu problema ocorre na limitação do acesso aos dados, uma que o serviço é 3G mas nem sempre funciona com tal tecnologia, pois os recursos no Brasil ainda são limitados necessitando ser utilizado o 2 EDGE, por exemplo.

É evidente que uma conexão 3G no momento que fica ociosa, o seu sinal desative para economizar o consumo de dados.

Uma solução seria manter o consumo ativo (através de *pings* por exemplo), mas não acho que seja uma alternativa viável, até porque você irá consumir a banda daquela conexão (e ultrapassar os limites de dados da ligacao eventualmente).

Outra solução é pedir ao(s) utilizador(es) do seu sistema que se reconectem/reactivem a conexão.

Comment: Ainda não obtive a resposta, infelizmente não posso ficar pedindo para os "clientes" ficarem desconectando, será que teria uma forma, de fazer essa reconexão através do C#?